# Global modals with Angular-UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I wonder if there's any possibility to move modal invoking code outside of working document and just call them from some common factory.

Currently I call dialogs with:

```
vm.showObjectInfo = function () {
    $rootScope.mObjectInfoInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'frmObjectInfo.html',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });

    $rootScope.mObjectInfoInstance.result.then(function () {
        // Refresh something in this document
    });
};
```

The drawback of this approach is that I need to write this code in every file where I want to call the dialog, which means that I create more instances of the same thing.

I wonder maybe I could move the `$rootScope.mObjectInfoInstance` code to some common factory and use like:

```
vm.showObjectInfo = function () {
    myFactory.objDialog.result.then(function () {
        // Refresh something in this document
    });
};
```

I tried to do so, but every time I end up with *undefined* objDialog, and if truth be told, I don't think I'm doing it right anyway.

Is there any suggestions, or some advice "best practice using common dialogs"?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem, I used the global JS variable for holding the modal instance and it made code very clean and light:

Here is the [demo plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/r8s0NBQ1u20KhRqjCO5A?p=preview)

Here is the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('Shared', ['ui.bootstrap']);    

// Create simple global var for holding modal instance outside of angular!
var GmObjectInfoInstance;

myApp.factory('sh', function($uibModal){
    // Implement openModal in your shared factory
    function openModal(page){
        return $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: page,
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        });       
    }
    // Expose function
    return {
        openModal: openModal
    }
});


myApp.controller('frm', ['sh', function (sh) {
  this.showObjectInfo = function () {

      // Call in any controller or factory or whatever
      GmObjectInfoInstance = sh.openModal("frmObjectInfo.html");
      GmObjectInfoInstance.result.then(function () {
         console.log("blah");
      });

  }

}]);


myApp.controller('modalCtrl', [ function () {
   // To close the dialog from inside, just use
   this.onCancelBtnClick = function(){
      GmObjectInfoInstance.close();
}       
}]);
```

So you don't need to use $rootScope and rewrite code many times, I find this approach very useful.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this answer has a score of -1? Are there any issues with this approach that need to be discussed?

Comment: The issue I can see is this approach will introduce difficulty in maintenance once project goes big. When there are numerous modal in the project, number of global variables will grow as well and issues might arise from there. (Basically one of many arguments on why global variables are bad)

Comment: @8749236 you are right, but when saying what is wrong with the method it would be nice to introduce the better alternative and not just criticism

Comment: @MovsarBekaev Yes, you are right, thank you. One can put an empty object into the factory "sh" of your solution, name and store modal instances within, retrieving them whenever needed; add management logic as they please.

Answer (score 0):

you could open modal logic into a factory:

```
factory('ModalService', function($uibModal){

    function openModal(options){
         var modalInstance= $uibModal.open(options);
         return modalInstance.result;
    }

    return {
        openModal: openModal
    }

})



//in controller:
vm.showObjectInfo = function () {

     ModalService.openModal({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'frmObjectInfo.html',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
     }).then(function(){
        // Refresh something in this document
     })

};
```

Comment: I updated my question, tried to implement it your way, but it still does not work